# adding data from different rows in a csv belonging to a common variable

Tags: python, csv, pandas, design-patterns, pandas-groupby

this is my csv excel file information:

```
  Receipt merchant    Address      Date    Time    Total price
    25007   A      ABC pte ltd   3/7/2016   10:40   12.30
    25008   A      ABC ptd ltd   3/7/2016   11.30   6.70
    25009   B      CCC ptd ltd   4/7/2016   07.35   23.40
    25010   A      ABC pte ltd   4/7/2016   12:40   9.90
```

how is it possible to add the 'Total Price' of each line together only if they belong to the same 'merchant', 'date' and 'time' then grouping them together in a list or dict, example: {['A','3/7/2016', '19.0'], ['A',4/7/2016, '9.90'],..}
My previous code does what i wanted except that i lack the code to count the total price for each same date and merchant.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from csv import reader
with open("assignment_info.csv") as f:
    next(f) 
    group_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for rec, name, _, dte, time, price in reader(f):
        group_dict[name, dte].extend(time)
    for v in group_dict.values():v.sort()    

from  pprint import pprint as pp
print 'Sales tracker:'
pp(dict(group_dict))
```

Comment: Are you grouping by merchant and date, or merchant, date, AND time? In your example case, you are doing the former.

Comment: the code i have is grouping different time to the same merchant and date. what i wish to do is adding the total price belonging to the same date and merchant then grouping it to its merchant and date.

Comment: think about moving to normal databases

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('assignment_info.csv')
df = df.groupby(['merchant', 'Date', 'Time']).sum().reset_index()
df
```

Comment: hoping to find an alternative method without pandas module thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer points out, `pandas` is an excellent library for this kind of data manipulation. My answer won't use `pandas` though.

A few issues:

- In your problem description, you state that you want to group by *three* columns, but in your example cases you are only grouping by two. Since the former makes more sense, I am only grouping by `name` and `date`
- You are looping and sorting each value, but for the life of me I can't figure out why.
- You declare the default type of the `defaultdict` a list and then `extend` with a string, which ends up giving you a (sorted!) list of characters. You don't really want to do this.
- Your example uses the syntax of a set: `{ [a,b,c], [d,e,f] }` but the syntax of a dict makes more sense: `{ (a, b): c, }`. I have changed the output to the latter.

Here is a working example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from csv import reader

with open("assignment_info.csv") as f:
    next(f) 
    group_dict = defaultdict(float)
    for rec, name, _, dte, time, price in reader(f):
        group_dict[name, dte] += float(price)
```

`group_dict` is now:

```
{('A', '3/7/2016'): 19.0, ('A', '4/7/2016'): 9.9, ('B', '4/7/2016'): 23.4}
```

I removed extra columns which aren't in your example: here's the file I worked with:

```
Receipt,merchant,Address,Date,Time,Total price
25007,A,ABC pte ltd,3/7/2016,10:40,12.30
25008,A,ABC ptd ltd,3/7/2016,11.30,6.70
25009,B,CCC ptd ltd,4/7/2016,07.35,23.40
25010,A,ABC pte ltd,4/7/2016,12:40,9.90
```

Comment: everything is fine, just that my output has to incude the time of sales also for each group of merchant and date such as {('A', '3/7/2016'): 19.0, 10:30,11:30} pls advice